# How to zoom in and out of text in Gedit?

Tags: 11.10, gedit, zooming

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. This seems to be an easy question, yet I cannot find an answer anywhere.

On pre-unity Ubuntu, I was using gedit-zoom plugin to zoom text in editor window in/out, either with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>, or by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ **scrolling mouse-wheel**. The same plugin does not seem to work in Ubuntu 11.10.

Any way I can get text zooming capability?

Comment: The functionality appears to be broken in 12.04. Ctrl+"-" and Ctrl+"0" work, while Ctrl+"+" and Ctrl+mousewheel do not.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[image: v2screenshot]

1. Under **Edit** → **Preferences** → **Plugins**, you can tick the **Text Size** box and zoom in with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

   - Click on [gedit-plugins](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gedit-plugins) [image: Install gedit-plugins] to install the Gedit plugins.
   - You can also [manually](ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gedit-plugins/) download/install the plugin.
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Trackpad scroll</kbd> (up/down) enables you, to zoom in and out as well, not only within gEdit, but also in your Webbrowser, File System etc.

Both possibilities work just fine in Ubuntu 11.10.

---

**Update information for Ubuntu 17.x.x, 18.x.x and later, as suggested by code_dredd** - tested and works:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gedit-plugin-text-size
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have the plugin you mentioned in here.

Comment: You can always install it (: You know how to..right!?

Comment: That was a hint to tell you to add the part about installing the plugin. ;)

Comment: indeed it was (: ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gedit-plugins/ however doesn't seem to work right now, but you can also type in "gedit" in "Ubuntu Software Center" and add plugins from there.

Comment: I edited the answer a bit. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: No, not at all!

Comment: The post doesn't make this *explicitly* clear, so just in case someone's still lost, **1)** open a terminal, **2)** run the following command: `sudo apt-get install -y gedit-plugins`, and **3)** enter your admin passphrase to proceed

Comment: Hello Ray, thank you for pointing it out. That's standards procedure!

Comment: These steps no longer work on Ubuntu 17.10. The `gedit-plugins` package does *not* include the `gedit-plugin-text-size` package with it. You now have to install the package manually: `sudo apt-get install -y gedit-plugin-text-size`.

Comment: @v2r It's better to avoid some assumptions :) BTW, one of your URLs is broken, and it'd be beneficial if you could update your answer to reflect the most recent steps necessary to accomplish this. You can look at my previous comment for that.

Comment: Thank you code_dredd! I added your suggestion to my original answer. Both links are working fine now: Sunday, May 5th 2019; 9:42:37 AM

Comment: 10 years old, and this answer went from being right, to being (slightly) wrong, back to being right again (in Ubuntu 21.10).

Comment: Worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

[image]You can change the fontsize in the preferences menu under the fonts tab

Comment: Maybe this is the only 'official' way. But, we are always looking for the fastest way, aren't we?

Comment: Thanks this worked for me since I don't have the plugin! +1

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see `"Text size"` plugin in the list of the plugins when I
opened `Preferences->Plugins` even after installing `gedit-plugins` package(via `apt install`) and restarting `gedit` few times. So, I downloaded manually the corresponding deb file(`gedit-plugin-text-size_3.22.0-2_amd64.deb`) from 
the launchpad (http://launchpadlibrarian.net/335063179/gedit-plugin-text-size_3.22.0-2_amd64.deb) for my `Ubuntu 17.10 x86_64` and installed it,
restarted gedit and saw `"Text size"` plugin thereafter in the list.
Enabled it and ***finally*** got the zoom-in/out feature with `mouse-scroll-wheel` I much needed.

Cheers.