# How to zoom in and out of text in Pluma?

Tags: fonts, gedit, ubuntu-mate, zooming, pluma

I am using newest version of Ubuntu mate (22.04 - Jammy jelly-fish), where the text editor is 'Pluma'.

Earlier, when I was in mint, I used to press 'Ctrl + scroll' for zooming in and out for changing font size. But, this is now not working in Pluma, please help. Just 'Ctrl' + '+/-' is also not working.

I found similar question for Gedit here ([How to zoom in and out of text in Gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108967/how-to-zoom-in-and-out-of-text-in-gedit)), and the answer suggested is to install a plugin 'Text-size'. So, I checked in Github page of pluma for similar plugin and it is not available there (https://github.com/mate-desktop/pluma).

Answer (score 0):

It is... not super intuative. A keyboard shortcut would help.

1. Do Edit > Preferences
2. Navigate to Font & Colors
3. Uncheck `Use the system fixed with font`
   [image: Screenshot of Pluma Preferences]
4. Where it says `Editor font:`, click on the current font (for me, it said `Monospace Regular 12`).
5. You can adjust the font size here (use the slider labeled `Size`, or replace `12` with your desired font size)
   [image: Screenshot of font picker]
6. Press `Select`, and then do `Close` to exit the preferences. Your font size is now changed

*I currently have a high-DPI display running i3wm (I use Arch BTW), and I just installed Pluma for this question, so that is why my window borders and scaling looks strange. But this should still work for you regardless.*

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. But I was looking for this particular option where I can simply 'Ctrl' + scroll, since I am working with some coding I like that dynamic zooming facility.